# Checking if sheet is present, not seeing that one is missing

Tags: excel, vba

I used the code below to import xml data from google maps api into excel, to quickly grab Lat and Lng for a list of locations. I had it working, but due to the speed of my requests it skipped a few. I deleted those worksheets, and implemented a bit of code to check if a worksheet is present or not (the second and fourth piece of code). However I can't get it to work properly, as it doesn't recognize the sheets as not being present for some reason. Could someone hint me to the error I made?

```
Sub Import_Xml()

Dim row As Integer
Dim strTargetFile As String
Dim wb As Workbook


Call Fill_Array_Locations
TotalRowsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Locations").UsedRange.Rows.Count

For row = 50 To TotalRowsData

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

.

```
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        If Worksheets(i).Name = Locations_Array(row, 1) Then
            exists = True
        End If
    Next i


        If Not exists Then
```

.

```
             Sheets.Add.Name = Locations_Array(row, 1)

                    strTargetFile = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" & Locations_Array(row, 2) & " " & Locations_Array(row, 3) & "&components=country:" & Locations_Array(row, 4) & "&key=********"
                        Set wb = Workbooks.OpenXML(Filename:=strTargetFile, LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList)
                            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
                                wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Locations_Array(row, 1)).Range("A1")
                    wb.Close False
```

.

```
        End If
```

.

```
Next row

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
exists = Empty
Next row

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Once the first row had been done exists would have the value TRUE, but would never lose it again. Inserting exists = Empty before going to the next row fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, but it wasn't the one that fixed your problem; to be useful to others in the future you should accept your own answer instead (if our little investigation helped a bit, just upvote mine)

Comment: I wanted to give you the credit for it, and as I can only accept my own answer in two days I wanted to mark the question answered. Maybe if I remember I will change it in two days time.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check:

1. Do you have the sheet called "Locations", and is it a Worksheets. If you're not sure replace `Worksheets("Locations")` with `Sheets("Locations")` or the exact name
2. This line: `If Worksheets(i).Name = Locations_Array(row, 1) Then`  is trying to find the sheet "CodeName" not sheet (Visible) Name. You can see the code name in the VBA editor name, top-left pane, then update `Locations_Array(row, 1)`   correspondingly
3. You should make sure that in the 3rd code you refer the the proper sheet: wb.Sheets(1) - verify wb.Sheets(1) CodeName and confirm that it's the one you need

Comment: Point 1 and 3 are not a problem, as I had the code running before, without the part that I added, sorry I didn't mention that before. In the top left corner I have a list of Sheet2 (1) till Sheet214 (213). Now there are some sheets missing as I deleted them because the importXML failed there. Now it should find those missing sheets and rerun the rest of the code for those.

Comment: I named a string test with test = Worksheets(i).Name, then looped through i. I saw a lot of jumping up and down of the names, but it are indeed the same names as are used for the worksheets.

Comment: If you have more than 200 sheets you need to make sure that all CodeNames are found (without exception - that's probably what's causing the issue). Checking just the first few will not reveal the mismatch. An easier way to check all of them is to add Worksheets to a watch, then expand the Name node and it should show you all 214 names in a list

Comment: I checked them manually, and they are all found. I also found out that I probably need to set the value of exists back to empty before the next row in the last piece of code. Any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: If exists is a boolean then use exists = Empty (or exists = False)

Comment: Thank you, I just found the same :)